# OpenApi generator automatically update functions code

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I'm using OpenAPI Generator to create a c++ pistache server stub.

Let's takes the next example:

1. I generate first stub version
2. Writing some code for several endpoint functions.
3. New YAML file comes in and i have to regenerate the whole stub.
4. **How do I include(in an automatically manner) the function bodies from the first generated stub to the new generated one ?**